# WPF ReactiveUI Control - take up all available space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, reactiveui

I know in WPF you can make controls take up all available space by placing them in a dockpanel. My reactive UI control doesn't stretch at all if it doesn't need that space. I have tried the dockpanel but it doesn't seem to work for Reactiveui:ViewModelViewHost controls.

this is in my shell view :

```xml
<DockPanel x:Name="ToolbarDockPanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <reactiveui:ViewModelViewHost x:Name="ToolbarView" Width="{Binding ActualWidth , ElementName=ToolbarDockPanel}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

And this is my view :

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="ICRx.App.UI.Shell.Toolbar.ToolbarView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ICRx.App.UI.Shell.Toolbar"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="768" MinWidth="">
    <Grid x:Name="ToolbarGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
        <Button x:Name="OpenButton"    Content="Open"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="5,10,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="CaptureButton" Content="Capture" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="5,5,5,5"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="SaveButton"    Content="Save"    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="5,5,5,10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="EditButton"    Content="Edit"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,10,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Grid x:Name="TemplateGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TemplateLabelColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="TemplateLabel"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Content="Template"
               Margin="5,0,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="TemplateComboBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,10,5,5"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="FilterGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="FilterLabel"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Content="Filter"
               Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TemplateLabel}"
               Margin="5,0,0,0"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="FilterComboBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding **HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"** **VerticalAlignment="Stretch"** to your ViewModelViewHost. (if that fails try it with the *HorizontalContentAlignment*/*VerticalContentAlignment*). I remember one of those will stretch your contents to take the entire available space.